# Schedule E vs Schedule C

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, landlord, schedule-c, schedule-e

I purchased (with a mortgage) a mixed-use building with an LLC in 2019. I rent the two retail/commercial units to two LLC businesses (one owned by me, and one owned by my wife). This building also has four residential apartments. I rent one to myself, one to my daughter, and I am remodeling two for airbnb to begin renting in 2021. I am late on filing my 2019 taxes. I am stuck on this point E vs. C.